# Incrementing a double pointer in C

Tags: c

This is the program which was asked in an interview to predict the output

```
  main()
  {
     char **p = 0;
     printf("%d\n", ++p);
  }
```

Can you please let me know why is the answer 4 here?

Comment: I hope you critiqued the code for either not including the explicit return type of `int` (required by C99 or C11), or for omitting `return 0;` (basically required for C89 as otherwise the return value from the program is indeterminate, but you're allowed to omit it from the end of `main()` in C99 or C11 and the result is as if you wrote `return 0;`, though IMO it is still best to include it).

Answer (score 1):

A char takes up 1 byte, but the pointer to that char takes up 4 bytes (an int32). So, `p` is actually a pointer to an int. When you increment a pointer, it moves forward by the amount of bytes of the underlying datatype. So, `p` moves forward by 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a `char` is one byte, but the size of a pointer (in 32bit code) is four bytes.  The double pointer means you're pointing *at* four byte quantities, thus

```
p ++
```

Advances the pointer four bytes (to supposedly the next `char *`), thus the output of the `printf` is 4.